# How to change the default JFrame Window color?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I am building an app for Windows using Java Swing/AWT interfaces in IntelliJ Idea. I am using a default `JFrame` to display my application GUI. However, I would like to change the default frame outline (window) colour to either transparent or custom colour.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

This is the window I have:
[image: This is what I have]

These two are the ones I am trying to achieve (transparency or custom colours):

[image: I would like to achieve either this]

Or this

[image: Or this]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: *"I have an additional question.."* Then start an additional thread. SO Q&As should focus on a single issue to make solutions easy to find later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom title bar by creating a new panel and set undecorated on your frame to hide default title bar
add your title to the new panel and buttons (exit, minimize...)

```
Frame.setUndecorated(true);
```